# Is this JSON code safe?

Tags: php, json, security

I have this code that checks if a json is valid and if it is, each object in the json is counted for 1 Dollar (currency on my website). Here is the code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
  $testJson = json_decode($_POST['data']);
  if($testJson) {
    $price = 0;
    foreach($testJson as $amount) 
      // I do something with $amount...
      $price++; // Augment the price
    }
  }
}
```

So basically if the `$_POST['data']` is `[{"item":2,"id":1092,"x":198,"y":-1}]`, then the price will be 1 Dollar. If it's `[{"item":2,"id":1092,"x":198,"y":-1},{"item":2,"id":1098,"x":198,"y":-1}]` the price would be 2 etc...

My question is, can someone manipulate the JSON so that they can buy an item for 0 Dollar even if there are multiple objects inside the JSON string?

Thank you

Comment: What concerns me more is, what if the price is $200? Or worse, ten grand?

Comment: @Prajwal No haha! The currency on my website (game) isn't the actual dollar

Comment: of course they can manipulate what is sent to server .... you can never trust user input

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10), then you can see that this code is vulnerable to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A8-Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).  I would also pay close attention to SQL Injection, as this is common in PHP because many application do not use an ORM.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I'm aware of that but this code is just a demo and not the actual one

Comment: @Jane you have not provided enough details for anyone to accurately answer your question.  If the OWASP top 10 doesn't answer your safety questions, than consider adding more details.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Code itself is safe (it's just a string). But you need to validate/sanitize **anything** that you retrieve out of the $_POST variable.

If you want to save the data in a mysql db, you should also sanitize it with prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to protect yourself against sql injections. Beware: mysql_real_escape_string does not provide any security, it just escapes characters within the string.

If at any point you wish to output the data that you retrieved from the $_POST in your website, you should also escape it (to make sure that you aren't caught by a cross-site-scripting attack).

I would also recommend validating the JSON against a JSONschema before applying any logic.